# SQL Error: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am receiving the following error when trying to execute the query below:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Arithmetic overflow error
>   converting expression to data type datetime.

```
WITH recursion (employeeid, schoolyear, loc1, effectivedate, d, enddate, currentrecord, Level)
AS
(
    select this.employeeid, this.schoolyear, this.loc1, this.effectivedate, this.effectivedate, this.enddate, this.currentrecord, 0 as level
    from Staging.EmployeeStaging2 as this 
    left Join Staging.EmployeeStaging2 as [last]
        on [last].enddate + 1 = this.effectivedate
    where ([last].employeeid=this.employeeid and [last].schoolyear=this.schoolyear) and [last].loc1 <> this.loc1 or [last].loc1 is NULL

    UNION ALL

    Select this.employeeid, this.schoolyear, this.loc1, this.effectivedate, last.d, this.enddate, this.currentrecord, level + 1
    from Staging.EmployeeStaging2 as this
    inner join recursion as [last]
        on [last].enddate+1 = this.effectivedate
    where ([last].employeeid=this.employeeid and [last].schoolyear=this.schoolyear) and [last].loc1 = this.loc1 and level < 3500)select employeeid, schoolyear, loc1, d as start, max(enddate) as end1, currentrecord
from recursion where schoolyear='1516'
group by employeeid, schoolyear, d, loc1, currentrecord, level 
order by employeeid, schoolyear, d
```

My fields effectivedate and enddate are both datetime.  An example of the data I'm working with is below.

```
employeeid  schoolyear  loc1    effectivedate           effectivedate           enddate                 currentrecord   level

986607200   1516        0151    2015-07-31 00:00:00.000 2015-07-31 00:00:00.000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 Y               0
```

I researched this issue and I understand it has something to do with subtracting 1 from the date fields.  At first I believed I was getting this error because the fields were date instead of datetime.  I alter the fields and I'm still receiving this error.  Will someone please help me understand what I am doing incorrectly?

Sorry for the long post; I'm new at this and still learning the proper etiquette for asking questions.  I should note that I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What does the 1 represent in:  "[last].enddate+1 = this.effectivedate" -- a day? an hour?  a minute?  a second?  a year? etc.   The dateadd function will allow you to specify that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: Arithmetic overflow comes from `enddate` (`9999-12-31 00:00:00.000` The End Of Times) plus one day (`last.enddate + 1`)

Comment: Thank you, @AlexKudryashev...I didn't realize that the end date was already defaulting to the "end of time".  I have since corrected the date and now the query is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use [**DATEADD**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

BTW you are using EndDate as Maximum Date:

For `SMALLDATETIME`

> Minimum Date is : 1 Jan 1900
>   Maximum Date is : 6 Jun 2079

For `DATETIME`

> Minimum Date is : i Jan 1753
>   Maximum Date is : 31 Dec 9999

```
WITH recursion (employeeid, schoolyear, loc1, effectivedate, d, enddate, currentrecord, Level)
AS
(
    select this.employeeid, this.schoolyear, this.loc1, this.effectivedate, this.effectivedate, this.enddate, this.currentrecord, 0 as level
    from Staging.EmployeeStaging2 as this 
    left Join Staging.EmployeeStaging2 as [last]
        on DATEADD(day,1, [last].enddate) = this.effectivedate
    where ([last].employeeid=this.employeeid and [last].schoolyear=this.schoolyear) and [last].loc1 <> this.loc1 or [last].loc1 is NULL

    UNION ALL

    Select this.employeeid, this.schoolyear, this.loc1, this.effectivedate, last.d, this.enddate, this.currentrecord, level + 1
    from Staging.EmployeeStaging2 as this
    inner join recursion as [last]
        on DATEADD(day,1, [last].enddate) = this.effectivedate
    where ([last].employeeid=this.employeeid and [last].schoolyear=this.schoolyear) and [last].loc1 = this.loc1 and level < 3500)select employeeid, schoolyear, loc1, d as start, max(enddate) as end1, currentrecord
from recursion where schoolyear='1516'
group by employeeid, schoolyear, d, loc1, currentrecord, level 
order by employeeid, schoolyear, d
```

Comment: `dateadd(day,1,'9999-12-31 00:00:00.000')` produces the same error. The problem is in data somewhere.